# Get total of Pandas column and row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame, as shown below,

```
     a   b   c
A  100  60  60
B   90  44  44
A   70  50  50
```

Now, I would like to get the total of column and row, skip c, as shown below,

```
     a   b   sum
A  170  110  280
B   90   44  134
```

So I do not know how to do, I'm in trouble, please help me, thank you, guys.

My example dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[100, 90,70], b=[60, 44,50],c=[60, 44,50]),index=["A", "B","A"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
    df.groupby(level=0)['a','b'].sum()
    .assign(sum=lambda x: x.sum(1))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#remove unnecessary column
df = df.drop('c', 1)
#get sum of rows
df['sum'] = df.sum(1)
#get sum per index
df = df.sum(level=0)
print (df)
     a    b  sum
A  170  110  280
B   90   44  134
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df["sum"] = df[["a","b"]].sum(axis=1) #Column-wise sum of "a" and "b"
df[["a", "b", "sum"]] #show all columns but not "c"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The `pandas` way is:

```
#create sum column
df['sum'] = df['a']+df['b']
#remove colimn c
df = df[['a', 'b', 'sum']]
```